# JQuery. Removing all listeners on delegated events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, listener

I have container with some elements. They have some delegated event listeners.

Like this

```
$('body').on('click', '.container .button', function() { ... });
```

I want to remove all listeners from all elements in the container (whatever event type and selector).

Like this

```
 $( "body" ).off("*", ".container *");
```

But it doesn't work.

Can anyone help? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 7):

**Updated answer**:

In the comments, you've said:

> Ok. I have a jsfiddle to explain the issue. http://jsfiddle.net/KT42n/3 I want to remove all handlers from all elements IN THE CONTAINER

and

> unfortunately in my case using of namespace is impossible

Ouch. That's going to make it very difficult, not least because some of the delegated handlers may relate to elements both inside and outside the container.

The only thing that comes to mind requires listing all of the event names you want to prevent (there aren't all that many):

```
$(".container").on("click mousedown mouseup etc.", false);
```

That will stop the event before it reaches `body`, and therefore before the delegated handler sees it: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/dazoxima/1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Stop Delegated Handlers Within Container</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Outside the container</p>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Inside the container</p>
  </div>
  <script>
    (function() {
      // Other handlers
      $("body").on("click", "p", function() {
        display("paragraph clicked");
      });

      // Prevent clicks within container
      $(".container").on("click mousedown etc", false);

      function display(msg) {
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = String(msg);
        document.body.appendChild(p);
      }
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Original answer**:

You can remove **all** handlers from `body` like this:

```
$("body").off();
```

That includes the delegated ones.

If you want to keep some of the handlers but not others, the simplest way I can think of is to namespace the events when you hook them up, e.g.:

```
$("body").on("click.foo", "selector", ...);
```

...and such. Then you can use the namespace to remove all of them:

```
$("body").off(".foo", "selector");
```

...or even just

```
$("body").off(".foo");
```

...to remove all of the namespaced ones entirely, not just the ones for that selector.

Example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/gisiniko/1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Removing All Delegated Handlers</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="clickable">Click me</div>
  <div class="mousemoveable">Mouse over me</div>
  <input type="button" id="theButton" value="Remove handlers">
  <script>
    (function() {
      $("body").on("click.foo", ".clickable", function() {
        display("click");
      });
      $("body").on("mousemove.foo", ".mousemoveable", function() {
        display("mousemove");
      });
      $("#theButton").click(function() {
        $("body").off(".foo");
      });
      function display(msg) {
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = String(msg);
        document.body.appendChild(p);
      }
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok. I have a jsfiddle to explain the issue. http://jsfiddle.net/KT42n/3 I want to remove all handlers from all elements IN THE CONTAINER

Comment: @T.J Crowder: well hope now you know that there are signatures where event name is optional and single string argument won't be always treated as an event name.

Comment: @see613: By far the best thing would be to use a namespace when hooking them up. Otherwise, you'd need to loop through the delegated handlers on `body` and see whether the elements they match (at that point in time) are in the container, and remove them; and I don' think jQuery makes any public API available for that. Further, the same delegated handler may relate to elements in and not in the container, which really makes it tricky.

Comment: @TilwinJoy: I said *"...an event name **and/or event namespace**..."* Your initial answer, for the first 10 minutes or so, was just completely wrong. You were passing in a selector, not a namespace. The updated answer is okay, other than being a duplicate of this one. If you're going to contribute on SO, you're going to have to get used to people downvoting without commenting (and commenting without downvoting) when you get things wrong. Everyone gets things wrong sometimes. Take it as exactly what it is: An indication the answer is "not useful," not a personal affront, and you'll do well.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder well you came up with this after reading the documentation now, before that your comment is also, "completely wrong."

Comment: unfortunately in my case using of namespace is impossible

Comment: @TilwinJoy: No, I came up with it by thinking about the problem. There's no need to be having a go at me.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry about that, didn't notice the and/or namespace.. :)

Comment: @see613: I've updated with one possible solution. Not pretty, requires listing a bunch of event names, but it should work.

Comment: @see613: Why? A handler that doesn't get triggered is effectively not there.

Answer (score 1):

`$("body").unbind()` remove all handlers

In Jquery online documentation, It has mentioned that it removes all the event handles attached to the element

> Event handlers attached with .bind() can be removed with .unbind().
>   (As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() and .off() methods are preferred to
>   attach and remove event handlers on elements.) In the simplest case,
>   with no arguments, .unbind() removes all handlers attached to the
>   elements:

Link : http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

If wrong please correct me

Comment: @War10ck: No, that's not true. But I don't know that `unbind` will unbind the *delegated* handlers hooked up with `delegate` or `on`.

Answer (score 1):

To remove all delegated events from an element without removing non-delegated events you just need to use the special value `**`.

`$('body').off('click', '**');`

Answer (score 0):

this would work
http://jsfiddle.net/KT42n/9/

sadly something like doesn't work

```
 $('body').undelegate('.container > * ','click');
```

Comment: what if some children don't have id? (because they may do)

Comment: I guess then you have to call undelegate/off to all items with your used selector and call delegate/on  with a new selector which doesn't include the ones from the .container

Comment: maybe this can help http://jsfiddle.net/KT42n/12/
i can't find any better solution because the selectors of the function delgate/on or undelegate/off all doens't allow complex selectors ...